# Unable to select control in Designer of VS 2008

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, controls

I'm unable to select controls in window form in VS 2008, whenever i try to select any control, the window will be selected instead.  It's as though they're read-only.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

*I'm using DiveElement sanddock in the form, will it be the cause of the abnormality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the list of controls in the properties window to select the control?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Although I couldn't figure out why, I was able to reset the form by right clicking and "Exclude from Project" followed by Project -> Add existing item and adding back the form.  Then it worked like it should.  Just wanted to share.